# Write, append DQL query results to excel in java using apache poi and DFC

Tags: java, apache-poi, documentum, dfc, documentum-dql

I have to write the dql query results to excel in java using apache poi and DFC. I have the following code written, this needs to be organized to handle efficiently. I tried writing to excel utility in other method, but this is not working correctly. So I stopped calling the method and written the code in the main method only. This is inefficient code.

In the first dql, I will fetch some attributes along with i_chronicle_id, this i_chronicle_id needs to be passed to the second dql for r_child_id. I need to add these attribute values to excel. It is doing if excel file doesn't exist create it, if exists write/append data. But after writing more amount of data this is getting slow. And when I used HSSFWorkbook the max row it can go is 1370. I didn't check for XSSFWorkbook. I tried searching all the excel writing posts, but not able to implement properly. So asking here. Please help me to organize the code efficiently and it should go for the next sheet if the sheet is full. Let me know for any information. Thanks in advance!

```
import com.documentum.com.DfClientX;
import com.documentum.com.IDfClientX;
import com.documentum.fc.client.*;
import com.documentum.fc.common.DfException;
import com.documentum.fc.common.IDfLoginInfo;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MedicalDevicesReport {

private static int j = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws DfException {

    String chronicleId;

    String documentId, documentName, title, domain, primaryGroup, subGroup, artifactName, versionLabel, status, creationDate,
            versionNum = null, is_current;

    ArrayList<String> author = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> reviewer = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> formatReviewer = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> approver = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<String> approvalCompletionTime = new ArrayList<>();

    int wfAbortCount = 0;

    String authorsF, reviewersF, formatReviewersF, approversF;
    String approvalCompletionTimeStamps;

    IDfClientX clientX  = new DfClientX();
    IDfClient dfClient = clientX.getLocalClient();
    IDfSessionManager sessionManager = dfClient.newSessionManager();
    IDfLoginInfo loginInfo = clientX.getLoginInfo();

    loginInfo.setUser("user");
    loginInfo.setPassword("password");
    sessionManager.setIdentity("docbase", loginInfo);

    IDfSession dfSession = sessionManager.getSession("docbase");
    System.out.println(dfSession);

    IDfQuery idfquery = new DfQuery();
    IDfCollection collection1 = null;

    IDfCollection collection2 = null;

    try {
        String dql1 = "select distinct r_object_id, object_name, title, authors, domain, primary_group, subgroup, artifact_name, r_version_label," +
                     "a_status, r_creation_date, i_chronicle_id from cd_quality_gmp_approved (all)  where r_creation_date between " +
                     "DATE('07/04/2018 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') and DATE('07/05/2018 23:59:59','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') order by r_creation_date";

        idfquery.setDQL(dql1);
        collection1 = idfquery.execute(dfSession, IDfQuery.DF_READ_QUERY);

        int i = 1;

        while(collection1 != null && collection1.next()) {
           chronicleId = collection1.getString("i_chronicle_id");
           author.add(collection1.getString("authors"));
           String dql2 = "select a.r_object_id, a.audited_obj_id, a.event_name as event_name, a.object_name as workflow_name, " +
                    "doc.object_name as document_name, ra.child_label as document_version, a.owner_name as supervisor_name, " +
                    "w.tracker_state as task_state, w.start_date as date_sent, a.user_name as task_performer, a.time_stamp as " +
                    "task_completion_time, a.string_2 as outcome, a.event_source as event_source, a.string_3 as delegation_from, " +
                    "a.string_4 as delegation_to from dm_audittrail a, d2c_workflow_tracker w, dm_relation ra, dm_sysobject doc " +
                    "where a.audited_obj_id in (select w.r_object_id from d2c_workflow_tracker w where r_object_id in (select " +
                    "distinct w.r_object_id from dm_relation r, d2c_workflow_tracker w where r.relation_name = 'D2_WF_TRACKER_DOCUMENT' " +
                    "and r.child_id = '" + chronicleId + "' and r.parent_id=w.r_object_id)) and a.audited_obj_id=w.r_object_id and " +
                    "ra.parent_id=w.r_object_id and a.audited_obj_id=ra.parent_id and ((a.event_name='d2_workflow_sent_task' and " +
                    "a.user_name not in (select user_name from dm_audittrail b where b.event_name in ('d2_workflow_rejected_task', " +
                    "'d2_workflow_forwarded_task', 'd2_delegation_delegated_task', 'd2_workflow_delegated_task', 'd2_workflow_added_note', " +
                    "'d2_workflow_aborted') and b.audited_obj_id=a.audited_obj_id)) or (a.event_name in ('d2_workflow_rejected_task', " +
                    "'d2_workflow_forwarded_task', 'd2_workflow_added_note', 'd2_workflow_aborted') and a.string_2 is not nullstring) or " +
                    "(a.event_name in ('d2_delegation_delegated_task','d2_workflow_delegated_task', 'd2_workflow_added_note', " +
                    "'d2_workflow_aborted'))) and doc.i_chronicle_id=ra.child_id and ra.child_label not In ('CURRENT',' ') order by 1 desc;";
            idfquery.setDQL(dql2);
            collection2 = idfquery.execute(dfSession, IDfQuery.DF_READ_QUERY);

            while(collection2 != null && collection2.next()) {
                String supervisorName = collection2.getString("supervisor_name");
                author.add(supervisorName);

                if(collection2.getString("event_name").equals("d2_workflow_aborted")) {
                    wfAbortCount++;
                }

                if(collection2.getString("event_source").equals("Review")) {
                    reviewer.add(collection2.getString("task_performer"));
                    continue;
                }

                if(collection2.getString("event_source").equals("Format Review")) {
                    if(collection2.getString("task_performer").contains("grp_wf_")) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        formatReviewer.add(collection2.getString("task_performer"));
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if((collection2.getString("event_source").equals("First Approval-no Sig")) ||
                        (collection2.getString("event_source").equals("First Approval")) ||
                        (collection2.getString("event_source").equals("Second Approval-no Sig")) ||
                        (collection2.getString("event_source").equals("Second Approval")) ||
                        (collection2.getString("event_source").contains("Approval"))) {
                    approver.add(collection2.getString("task_performer"));
                    approvalCompletionTime.add(collection2.getString("task_completion_time"));
                }
            }

            documentId = collection1.getString("r_object_id");
            documentName = collection1.getString("object_name");
            title = collection1.getString("title");
            domain = collection1.getString("domain");
            primaryGroup = collection1.getString("primary_group");
            subGroup = collection1.getString("subgroup");
            artifactName = collection1.getString("artifact_name");
            versionLabel = collection1.getString("r_version_label");
            status = collection1.getString("a_status");
            creationDate = collection1.getString("r_creation_date");

            String temp = versionLabel;
            String[] parts = temp.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d\\.?\\d)");
            if(parts.length > 1) {
                versionNum = parts[1];
                is_current = parts[0];
            } else {
                is_current = parts[0];
            }
            String versionLabelF = versionNum + " " + is_current;

            List<String> authors = author.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<String> reviewers = reviewer.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<String> formatReviewers = formatReviewer.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<String> approvers = approver.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

            List<String> approvalCompletionTimeStamp = approvalCompletionTime.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

            authorsF = authors.toString().substring(1, authors.toString().length() - 1);
            reviewersF = reviewers.toString().substring(1, reviewers.toString().length() - 1);
            formatReviewersF = formatReviewers.toString().substring(1, formatReviewers.toString().length() - 1);
            approversF = approvers.toString().substring(1, approvers.toString().length() - 1);

            approvalCompletionTimeStamps = approvalCompletionTimeStamp.toString().substring(1, approvalCompletionTimeStamp.toString().length() - 1);

            author.clear();
            reviewer.clear();
            formatReviewer.clear();
            approver.clear();

            approvalCompletionTime.clear();

            Workbook workbook = null;
            File file = new File("C:\\SubWay TRC\\fetched_reports\\mdreport.xlsx");

            try {
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    if (!file.toString().endsWith(".xls")) {
                        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                        workbook.createSheet();
                    }
                } else {
                    workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(file));
                    workbook.createSheet();
                }
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

            Row row;
            try {
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(j);
                int last_row = sheet.getLastRowNum();
                System.out.println(last_row);
                row = sheet.createRow(++last_row);

                Map<Integer, Object[]> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put(i, new Object[] {documentId, documentName, title, domain, primaryGroup, subGroup, artifactName, versionLabelF,
                        status, creationDate, authorsF, reviewersF, formatReviewersF, approversF, approvalCompletionTimeStamps, wfAbortCount});

                Set<Integer> key_set = data.keySet();

                for(Integer key: key_set) {
                    Object[] obj_arr = data.get(key);
                    int cell_num = 0;
                    for(Object obj: obj_arr) {
                        Cell cell = row.createCell(cell_num++);
                        if(obj instanceof String) {
                            cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                        }
                    }
                }

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\SubWay TRC\\fetched_reports\\mdreport.xlsx", false);
                workbook.write(out);
                out.close();
                System.out.println("Data added successfully");

            } catch (IOException  e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    } finally {
        if(collection1 != null) {
            collection1.close();
        }
        if(collection2 != null) {
            collection2.close();
        }
        if(dfSession != null) {
            sessionManager.release(dfSession);
        }
    }
}

private static void executeWorkflowAudit(IDfQuery idfquery, IDfSession dfSession, IDfCollection attributeCollection,
                                         String chronicleId, int i) throws DfException {

    IDfCollection collection;

    String documentId, documentName, title, domain, primaryGroup, subGroup, artifactName, versionLabel, status, creationDate,
            versionNum = null, is_current;

    ArrayList<String> author = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> reviewer = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> formatReviewer = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> approver = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<String> approvalCompletionTime = new ArrayList<>();

    int wfAbortCount = 0;

   String authorsF, reviewersF, formatReviewersF, approversF;
   String approvalCompletionTimeStamps;

    String dql = "select a.r_object_id, a.audited_obj_id, a.event_name as event_name, a.object_name as workflow_name, " +
                "doc.object_name as document_name, ra.child_label as document_version, a.owner_name as supervisor_name, " +
                "w.tracker_state as task_state, w.start_date as date_sent, a.user_name as task_performer, a.time_stamp as " +
                "task_completion_time, a.string_2 as outcome, a.event_source as event_source, a.string_3 as delegation_from, " +
                "a.string_4 as delegation_to from dm_audittrail a, d2c_workflow_tracker w, dm_relation ra, dm_sysobject doc " +
                "where a.audited_obj_id in (select w.r_object_id from d2c_workflow_tracker w where r_object_id in (select " +
                "distinct w.r_object_id from dm_relation r, d2c_workflow_tracker w where r.relation_name = 'D2_WF_TRACKER_DOCUMENT' " +
                "and r.child_id = '" + chronicleId + "' and r.parent_id=w.r_object_id)) and a.audited_obj_id=w.r_object_id and " +
                "ra.parent_id=w.r_object_id and a.audited_obj_id=ra.parent_id and ((a.event_name='d2_workflow_sent_task' and " +
                "a.user_name not in (select user_name from dm_audittrail b where b.event_name in ('d2_workflow_rejected_task', " +
                "'d2_workflow_forwarded_task', 'd2_delegation_delegated_task', 'd2_workflow_delegated_task', 'd2_workflow_added_note', " +
                "'d2_workflow_aborted') and b.audited_obj_id=a.audited_obj_id)) or (a.event_name in ('d2_workflow_rejected_task', " +
                "'d2_workflow_forwarded_task', 'd2_workflow_added_note', 'd2_workflow_aborted') and a.string_2 is not nullstring) or " +
                "(a.event_name in ('d2_delegation_delegated_task','d2_workflow_delegated_task', 'd2_workflow_added_note', " +
                "'d2_workflow_aborted'))) and doc.i_chronicle_id=ra.child_id and ra.child_label not In ('CURRENT',' ') order by 1 desc;";

    idfquery.setDQL(dql);
    collection = idfquery.execute(dfSession, IDfQuery.READ_QUERY);

    while(collection != null && collection.next()) {
        String supervisorName = collection.getString("supervisor_name");
        author.add(supervisorName);

        if(collection.getString("event_name").equals("d2_workflow_aborted")) {
            wfAbortCount++;
        }

        if(collection.getString("event_source").equals("Review")) {
            reviewer.add(collection.getString("task_performer"));
            continue;
        }

        if(collection.getString("event_source").equals("Format Review")) {
           if(collection.getString("task_performer").contains("grp_wf_")) {
               continue;
           } else {
               formatReviewer.add(collection.getString("task_performer"));
               continue;
           }
        }

        if((collection.getString("event_source").equals("First Approval-no Sig")) ||
                (collection.getString("event_source").equals("First Approval")) ||
                (collection.getString("event_source").equals("Second Approval-no Sig")) ||
                (collection.getString("event_source").equals("Second Approval"))) {
            approver.add(collection.getString("task_performer"));
            approvalCompletionTime.add(collection.getString("task_completion_time"));
        }

        documentId = attributeCollection.getString("r_object_id");
        documentName = attributeCollection.getString("object_name");
        title = attributeCollection.getString("title");
        domain = attributeCollection.getString("domain");
        primaryGroup = attributeCollection.getString("primary_group");
        subGroup = attributeCollection.getString("subgroup");
        artifactName = attributeCollection.getString("artifact_name");
        versionLabel = attributeCollection.getString("r_version_label");
        status = attributeCollection.getString("a_status");
        creationDate = attributeCollection.getString("r_creation_date");

        String temp = versionLabel;
        String[] parts = temp.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d\\.?\\d)");
        if(parts.length > 1) {
            versionNum = parts[1];
            is_current = parts[0];
        } else {
            is_current = parts[0];
        }
        String versionLabelF = versionNum + " " + is_current;

        List<String> authors = author.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> reviewers = reviewer.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> formatReviewers = formatReviewer.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> approvers = approver.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<String> approvalCompletionTimeStamp = approvalCompletionTime.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

        authorsF = authors.toString().substring(1, authors.toString().length() - 1);
        reviewersF = reviewers.toString().substring(1, reviewers.toString().length() - 1);
        formatReviewersF = formatReviewers.toString().substring(1, formatReviewers.toString().length() - 1);
        approversF = approvers.toString().substring(1, approvers.toString().length() - 1);

        approvalCompletionTimeStamps = approvalCompletionTimeStamp.toString().substring(1, approvalCompletionTimeStamp.toString().length() - 1);

        author.clear();
        reviewer.clear();
        formatReviewer.clear();
        approver.clear();

        approvalCompletionTime.clear();

        Workbook workbook = null;
        File file = new File("C:\\SubWay TRC\\fetched_reports\\wfperf.xls");

        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                if (!file.toString().endsWith(".xlsx")) {
                    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                    workbook.createSheet();
                }
            } else {
                workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(file));
                workbook.createSheet();
            }
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        Row row;
        try {
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(j);
            int last_row = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            System.out.println(last_row);
            if(last_row == 1370) {
                ++j;
                sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(j);
                int last_row_new = sheet.getLastRowNum();
                row = sheet.createRow(++last_row_new);
            } else {
                row = sheet.createRow(++last_row);
            }

            Map<Integer, Object[]> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put(i, new Object[] {documentId, documentName, title, domain, primaryGroup, subGroup, artifactName, versionLabelF,
                    status, creationDate, authorsF, reviewersF, formatReviewersF, approversF, approvalCompletionTimeStamps, wfAbortCount});

            Set<Integer> key_set = data.keySet();

            for(Integer key: key_set) {
                Object[] obj_arr = data.get(key);
                int cell_num = 0;
                for(Object obj: obj_arr) {
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(cell_num++);
                    if(obj instanceof String) {
                        cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                    }
                }
            }

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\SubWay TRC\\fetched_reports\\wfperf.xls", false);
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Data added successfully");

        } catch (IOException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Sorry but your question isn't really good material for question at SO. You are basically asking for reorganization of your code with little accent - it doesn't really works fine. Please, put more effort to it isolate your problem and maybe people will help you. As for the code quality - bear with it. Learn how to write well. It's a process and you are payed for that. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code for organizing, in your method executeWorkflowAudit(), you are collecting all the attribute data in while loop only, what if the collection has no results, this would skip the data what you want to add apart from workflow data. Place the attribute data outside of while loop, so this won't skip adding initial collection data. I have separated the session manager and getting session parts also. Similarly, you can keep DQL queries in separate class like QueryConstants and access here. This should work, please have a try. I'm not sure about the maximum row count. Will update if I could find any. Hope, this helps you! Anyway you can refer [this](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf) for writing huge data to excel.

```
import com.documentum.com.DfClientX;
import com.documentum.com.IDfClientX;
import com.documentum.fc.client.*;
import com.documentum.fc.common.DfException;
import com.documentum.fc.common.IDfLoginInfo;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MedicalDevicesReport {

private static int j = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws DfException {

    String chronicleId;

    ArrayList<String> author = new ArrayList<>();

    IDfSessionManager sessionManager = getSessionManager("docbase", "user", "password");
    IDfSession dfSession = sessionManager.getSession("docbase");

    System.out.println(dfSession);

    IDfQuery idfquery = new DfQuery();
    IDfCollection collection;

    try {

        String dql = "select distinct r_object_id, object_name, title, authors, domain, primary_group, subgroup, artifact_name, r_version_label," +
                "a_status, r_creation_date, i_chronicle_id from cd_quality_gmp_approved (all)  where r_creation_date between " +
                "DATE('07/04/2018 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') and DATE('07/05/2018 23:59:59','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') order by r_creation_date";

        idfquery.setDQL(dql);
        collection = idfquery.execute(dfSession, IDfQuery.DF_READ_QUERY);

        int i = 1;

        File file = new File("C:\\SubWay TRC\\fetched_reports\\mdreport.xlsx");

        while(collection != null && collection.next()) {
            chronicleId = collection.getString("i_chronicle_id");
            author.add(collection.getString("authors"));
            executeWorkflowAudit(dfSession, collection, idfquery, chronicleId, author, i, file);
            i++;
        }

    } finally {
        cleanup(sessionManager, dfSession);
    }
}

private static void executeWorkflowAudit(IDfSession dfSession, IDfCollection attributeCollection, IDfQuery idfquery, String chronicleId, ArrayList<String> author,
                                         int i, File file) throws DfException {

    IDfCollection collection;

    String documentId, documentName, title, domain, primaryGroup, subGroup, artifactName, versionLabel, status, creationDate,
            versionNum = null, is_current;

    ArrayList<String> reviewer = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> formatReviewer = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> approver = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<String> approvalCompletionTime = new ArrayList<>();

    String authorsF, reviewersF, formatReviewersF, approversF;
    String approvalCompletionTimeStamps;

    int wfAbortCount = 0;

    String dql = "select a.r_object_id, a.audited_obj_id, a.event_name as event_name, a.object_name as workflow_name, " +
            "doc.object_name as document_name, ra.child_label as document_version, a.owner_name as supervisor_name, " +
            "w.tracker_state as task_state, w.start_date as date_sent, a.user_name as task_performer, a.time_stamp as " +
            "task_completion_time, a.string_2 as outcome, a.event_source as event_source, a.string_3 as delegation_from, " +
            "a.string_4 as delegation_to from dm_audittrail a, d2c_workflow_tracker w, dm_relation ra, dm_sysobject doc " +
            "where a.audited_obj_id in (select w.r_object_id from d2c_workflow_tracker w where r_object_id in (select " +
            "distinct w.r_object_id from dm_relation r, d2c_workflow_tracker w where r.relation_name = 'D2_WF_TRACKER_DOCUMENT' " +
            "and r.child_id = '" + chronicleId + "' and r.parent_id=w.r_object_id)) and a.audited_obj_id=w.r_object_id and " +
            "ra.parent_id=w.r_object_id and a.audited_obj_id=ra.parent_id and ((a.event_name='d2_workflow_sent_task' and " +
            "a.user_name not in (select user_name from dm_audittrail b where b.event_name in ('d2_workflow_rejected_task', " +
            "'d2_workflow_forwarded_task', 'd2_delegation_delegated_task', 'd2_workflow_delegated_task', 'd2_workflow_added_note', " +
            "'d2_workflow_aborted') and b.audited_obj_id=a.audited_obj_id)) or (a.event_name in ('d2_workflow_rejected_task', " +
            "'d2_workflow_forwarded_task', 'd2_workflow_added_note', 'd2_workflow_aborted') and a.string_2 is not nullstring) or " +
            "(a.event_name in ('d2_delegation_delegated_task','d2_workflow_delegated_task', 'd2_workflow_added_note', " +
            "'d2_workflow_aborted'))) and doc.i_chronicle_id=ra.child_id and ra.child_label not In ('CURRENT',' ') order by 1 desc";

    idfquery.setDQL(dql);
    collection = idfquery.execute(dfSession, IDfQuery.READ_QUERY);

    while(collection != null && collection.next()) {
        String supervisorName = collection.getString("supervisor_name");
        author.add(supervisorName);

        if(collection.getString("event_name").equals("d2_workflow_aborted")) {
            wfAbortCount++;
        }

        if(collection.getString("event_source").equals("Review")) {
            reviewer.add(collection.getString("task_performer"));
            continue;
        }

        if(collection.getString("event_source").equals("Format Review")) {
            if(collection.getString("task_performer").contains("grp_wf_")) {
                continue;
            } else {
                formatReviewer.add(collection.getString("task_performer"));
                continue;
            }
        }

        if((collection.getString("event_source").equals("First Approval-no Sig")) ||
                (collection.getString("event_source").equals("First Approval")) ||
                (collection.getString("event_source").equals("Second Approval-no Sig")) ||
                (collection.getString("event_source").equals("Second Approval")) ||
                (collection.getString("event_source").contains("Approval"))) {
            approver.add(collection.getString("task_performer"));
            approvalCompletionTime.add(collection.getString("task_completion_time"));
        }
    }

    documentId = attributeCollection.getString("r_object_id");
    documentName = attributeCollection.getString("object_name");
    title = attributeCollection.getString("title");
    domain = attributeCollection.getString("domain");
    primaryGroup = attributeCollection.getString("primary_group");
    subGroup = attributeCollection.getString("subgroup");
    artifactName = attributeCollection.getString("artifact_name");
    versionLabel = attributeCollection.getString("r_version_label");
    status = attributeCollection.getString("a_status");
    creationDate = attributeCollection.getString("r_creation_date");

    String temp = versionLabel;
    String[] parts = temp.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d\\.?\\d)");
    if(parts.length > 1) {
        versionNum = parts[1];
        is_current = parts[0];
    } else {
        is_current = parts[0];
    }
    String versionLabelF = versionNum + " " + is_current;

    List<String> authors = author.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<String> reviewers = reviewer.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<String> formatReviewers = formatReviewer.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<String> approvers = approver.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<String> approvalCompletionTimeStamp = approvalCompletionTime.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    authorsF = authors.toString().substring(1, authors.toString().length() - 1);
    reviewersF = reviewers.toString().substring(1, reviewers.toString().length() - 1);
    formatReviewersF = formatReviewers.toString().substring(1, formatReviewers.toString().length() - 1);
    approversF = approvers.toString().substring(1, approvers.toString().length() - 1);

    approvalCompletionTimeStamps = approvalCompletionTimeStamp.toString().substring(1, approvalCompletionTimeStamp.toString().length() - 1);

    author.clear();
    reviewer.clear();
    formatReviewer.clear();
    approver.clear();

    approvalCompletionTime.clear();

    Workbook workbook = null;

    try {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (!file.toString().endsWith(".xls")) {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                workbook.createSheet();
            }
        } else {
            workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(file));
            workbook.createSheet();
        }
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    Row row;
    try {
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(j);
        int last_row = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        System.out.println(last_row);
        row = sheet.createRow(++last_row);

        Map<Integer, Object[]> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put(i, new Object[] {documentId, documentName, title, domain, primaryGroup, subGroup, artifactName, versionLabelF,
                status, creationDate, authorsF, reviewersF, formatReviewersF, approversF, approvalCompletionTimeStamps, wfAbortCount});

        Set<Integer> key_set = data.keySet();

        for(Integer key: key_set) {
            Object[] obj_arr = data.get(key);
            int cell_num = 0;
            for(Object obj: obj_arr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cell_num++);
                if(obj instanceof String) {
                    cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                }
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\SubWay TRC\\fetched_reports\\mdreport.xlsx", false);
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Data added successfully");

    } catch (IOException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(collection != null) {
            collection.close();
        }
    }
}

private static IDfSessionManager getSessionManager(String docbase, String userName, String password) throws DfException {

    IDfClientX clientX = new DfClientX();
    IDfClient client = clientX.getLocalClient();

    IDfSessionManager sessionManager = client.newSessionManager();

    IDfLoginInfo loginInfo = clientX.getLoginInfo();
    loginInfo.setUser(userName);
    loginInfo.setPassword(password);

    sessionManager.setIdentity(docbase, loginInfo);

    return sessionManager;
}

public static void cleanup(IDfSessionManager sessionManager, IDfSession session) {

    if(sessionManager != null && session != null) {
        sessionManager.release(session);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks Srivastava for the clarification. This is lot better!